# Mapreduce different keys produce different number of messages

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, cloudera

I have a small issue with mapreduce job having different number of messages if I use two different classes for the Key.
The problem is the classes should be essentially the same in regard to the Mapreduce.

Case 1 :

```
class Key1{
    private LongWritable id = new LongWritable();
    private LongWritable timestamp = new LongWritable();
}
```

With this Key class, the MR job produces 9871431 results

Case 2:

```
class Key1{
    private LongWritable id = new LongWritable();
    private LongWritable timestamp = new LongWritable();
    private LongWritable field1 = new LongWritable();
    .....
    private LongWritable fieldN = new LongWritable();
}
```

The difference is only that the Key has more fields. So far, different results can be explained
BUT :
My Grouping comparator only uses only the ID field

```
public class NaturalKeyGroupingComparator extends WritableComparator {

    protected NaturalKeyGroupingComparator() {
        super(Key1.class, true);
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public int compare(WritableComparable a, WritableComparable b) {
        Key1 p1 = (Key) a;
        Key p2 = (Key) b;

        return p1.getId().compareTo(p2.getId());
    }
}
```

Same with my partitioner

```
public class MMSIPairPartitioner extends Partitioner<Key1, TrackingPair> {

    public int getPartition(Key1 key, TrackingPair value, int numPartitions) {
        return key.getId().hashCode() % numPartitions;
    }
}
```

So what i think is, that i can using Key1 should produce exactly the same number of documents as the fields used in determining the partition are the same for Key1 and Key2.

The Key1 though, `produces 2 documents less`.

The reduce part is the same for both cases.

Both Key implementations have this compare method as I am using secondary sorting

```
public int compareTo(Key pair) {
        int compareValue = this.id.compareTo(pair.getId());
        if (compareValue == 0) {
            compareValue = this.timestamp.compareTo(pair.getTimestamp());
        }
        return compareValue;
    }
```

So why would Key class with more fields(but not used for sorting or partitioning) produce different number of results (2 less in this case) ?

Comment: Are there any differences in other counters (in particular "reduce input groups" and "reduce input values")?

Comment: Nope. input groups are the same as are the reduce input records